# How to execute methods which returns different objects using Executors in Java

Tags: java, executorservice

I have 4 methods which return List of Different classes. Lets Say

```
public List<A> getA(String param1, String param2){
 //some code here
}
public List<B> getB(String param1, String param2){
 //some code here
}

public List<C> getC(String param1, String param2){
 //some code here
}
public List<D> getD(String param1, String param2){
 //some code here
}
```

I want to execute these 4 methods simultaneously, I am using Callable and Executor as bellow

```
Callable<List<A>> collableA = new Callable<List<A>>() {
        @Override
        public List<A> call() throws Exception {
            return getA();
        }
    };
Callable<List<B>> collableB = new Callable<List<B>>() {
        @Override
        public List<B> call() throws Exception {
            return getB();
        }
    };
Callable<List<D>> collableD = new Callable<List<D>>() {
        @Override
        public List<D> call() throws Exception {
            return getD();
        }
    };
Callable<List<C>> collableC = new Callable<List<C>>() {
        @Override
        public List<C> call() throws Exception {
            return getC();
        }
    };

// add to a list
List<Callable> taskList = new ArrayList<Callable>();
taskList.add(collableA );
taskList.add(collableB);
taskList.add(collableC);
taskList.add(collableD);
//create a pool executor with 4 threads
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

Future<List<FrozenFrameAlert>>  futureFrozen = executor.submit(taskList); 
// getting error here submit() not accepting taskList
```

I tried with `InvokeAll()` and `invokeAny()` methods but no method is accepting this `taskList`

Comment: `invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)` should work. how are you using it or what error are you getting? `executor.submit` only accepts a single task.

Comment: If I use `invokeAll()` getting this error 
`The method invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (List<Callable>)`
For `submit()` getting this error 
`The method submit(Callable<T>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (List<Callable>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `submit()` for each callable; that will give you four futures, each with the right type:

```
Future<List<A>> futureA = executor.submit(callableA);
Future<List<B>> futureB = executor.submit(callableB);
etc.
```

If you need the results of all four futures before you continue, you can just block on each one in turn:

```
List<A> resultA = futureA.get();
List<B> resultB = futureB.get();
etc.
```

To do something more generalized, you'd need to figure out a way in which all these lists are "the same". If you don't use them the same way, though, it doesn't matter that they're different types.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, you simply need to use the generic interface `Callable<T>` instead of `Callable` for the `ExecutorService#invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)` method to accept the `List<Callable<T>>`.

Example:

```
List<Callable<List<?>>> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
taskList.add(() -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
taskList.add(() -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c")));
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
List<Future<List<?>>> futureList = executor.invokeAll(taskList);

for (Future<List<?>> future : futureList) {
    System.out.println(future.get());
}
```

If you really have different return types you still need to use `Callable<T>` with some appropriate type, like a super interface or `Object` at least.

Comment: No,Its not working for me, 
I created `taskList` as you seggested.
`List<Callable<Object>> taskList = new ArrayList<>();`
but I am getting following error when adding object to list like
`taskList.add(collableD );`

`The method add(Callable<Object>) in the type List<Callable<Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (Callable<List<FrozenFrameAlert>>)`

Comment: It should still work with `List<Callable<Object>>`, but I just tested with `List<Callable<List<?>>> taskList` and that is probably better in your case when all your callable objects return a generic list. It works with my test cases with a Callable returning a `List<Integer>` and another with `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that your

```
List<Callable> taskList = new ArrayList<Callable>();
```

is not generic it should be some thing like .

```
List<Callable<List>> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
```